# Time line google chart based on column show same colour ? ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, timeline, jsapi

I am developing a timeline chart that shows color based on a column , my feilds of date is datetime , 
I have found a js fiddle similar to my example just little modification i did added time but it works fine for single row not for multiple rows here is my js fiddle link with my data

[JS FIDDLE FOR TIME LINE CHART (mine)](http://jsfiddle.net/7A88H/334/)

Now the example i am trying to copy is that link

[js fiddle (example)](http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/7A88H/)

i changed the default colur scheme

```
            colors.push(colorMap[dataTable.getValue(i, 2)]);
```

so take color and push

then the category map

```
     var colorMap = {
            Zero: '#ffffff',
            One: '#00b050',   // green
            Two: '#4bc0c0',   // Aqua
            Three: '#FFC000',   // Yellow
            Four: '#C2EFE6',   // Light Sky blue
            Five: '#935392',   // Purple
            Six: '#e48a89',   // Light maroon
            Sev: '#339cff'    // Blue
        }
```

**Can any body modify the fiddle and tell me what i was missing** and also i have checked that with only date by removing time So this is not a issue

**EDIT**

I am posting more code on request but fiddle also contain complete code A-Z

for setting colormap

```
    for (var i = 0; i < dataTable.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
    colors.push(colorMap[dataTable.getValue(i, 2)]);
}
```

options for setting colors scheme

```
     var options = {
    timeline: { 
        groupByRowLabel: true,
        rowLabelStyle: {
            fontName: 'Roboto Condensed',
            fontSize: 14,
            color: '#333333'
        },
        barLabelStyle: {
            fontName: 'Roboto Condensed',
            fontSize: 14
        }
    },                          
    avoidOverlappingGridLines: true,
    height: chartHeight,
    width: '100%',
    colors: colors
};

// use a DataView to hide the category column from the Timeline
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(dataTable);
view.setColumns([0, 1, 3, 4]);

chart.draw(view, options);
```

Datatable column and rows like this

```
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Group' });
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'ID' });
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Category' });
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
dataTable.addRows([['Bay', ' ', 'Sev', new Date(2014, 0, 1, 9, 0, 0), new Date(2014, 0, 1, 9, 10, 0)], ['Bay', ' ', 'Sev', new Date(2014, 0, 1, 9, 10, 0), new Date(2014, 0, 1, 9, 20, 0)]]);
```

Based on third column i want color selection So index is 2

Comment: WE BOTH ARE WORKING ON SAME KINDLY HELP ASAP

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, you should post all relevant code in the question itself, instead of external resource (jsfiddle)

Comment: ok mam updated and added code now i think its much better to modify fiddle or tell some think i apply changes and test @slawekwin

Comment: @FaiqahGondal it's ok to have the fiddle aside from the code in the question body, but you have to consider that the question might be useful to people in the future, when outside resources might not be available any more.

Comment: @slawekwin Can anybody answer too are you looking

Comment: WAITING....@slawekwin CAN ANYBODY HELP TOO

Comment: latest updated fiddle can any body tell me how to view 1st column of table in popup instead of 2 http://jsfiddle.net/7A88H/336/